# How to use fetch function and show api response on component ? Custom fetch response is not passing to component

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, fetch-api, react-component

After Fetch /Vehicles from api I wanted to show them in component but inside useFetch function I can console.log res.data but inside the Trucks component I could not map trucks.

**My Custom useFetch function:**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const useFetch = (url) => {
  const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'api url',
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.token}` },
  });

  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(true);

  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const abortCont = new AbortController();

    setTimeout(() => {

      api
        .get(url)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
          if (!res.ok) {
            throw Error('Could not with fetch data');
          }
        })
        .then((data) => {
          data.json();
          console.log(data);
          setIsPending(false);
          setError(null);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          if (err.name === 'AbortError') {
            console.log('fetch aborted');
          } else {
            setIsPending(false);
            setError(err.message);
          }
        });
    }, 1000);

    return () => abortCont.abort();
  }, [url]); 
  return { data, isPending, error };
};

export default useFetch;
```

I used this custom useFetch function and could get data (inside the function) its not usable to render
Some possible reasons I thought ;

- useFetch function may not return data properly
- I may need to use stringify or json function for API respond

**Trucks Component:**

```
const Trucks = () => {
  const { data: trucks, error, isPending } = useFetch('/vehicles');// 
  console.log('they are ' + { trucks }); //console output ->[object,Object]

  return (Some Jsx)};

export default Trucks;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your Hook itself that I can see.

The first thing is that you never call `setData`. This means that although you are fetching the data inside your hook and consoling it out, you never set the `data` object to hold the retrieved data.

The second thing is that the second `then` isn't actually doing anything with the data you are retrieving. You can handle this all inside the first statement as such

```js
.then((res) => {
    setData(res.data);
    setIsPending(false);
    if (!res.ok) {
        setIsPending(false);
        throw Error("Could not with fetch data");
    }
})
```

Once you do this you should be able to call your hook inside the related component, and render it using some JSX. Just make sure to add a check for `isPending` and display some sort of loading screen before actually rendering your data.

Another note, when you use axios, you do not need to call data.json(). That is something that is required for the `fetch` API but axios just requires you to call `res.data` when resolving the promise

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It just worked and I got it.